# Consul .NET client: how to track visibility of registered services?

Tags: c#, .net, consul

What I'm looking for is a possibility for live monitoring of registered services using Consul, and be able to detect when they are marked as dead i.e. due to failed health check.

Consul documentation describes a [watch command](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/watch.html), that can be used to watch over changes in various consul capabilities. However when looking at .NET client i.e. [PlayFab/consuldotnet](https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet) I cannot find such API exposed.

Comment: It is the same API as the ordinary GET requests, you just pass a token/index for the latest change (0 at first request) then get the next token from the request

Comment: https://github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-dotnet/blob/5cdacb684538fcef3b4066296cb751bf3d150e00/src/ClusterProviders/Proto.Cluster.Consul/ConsulProvider.cs#L147

Comment: That being said, we have replaced this with ordinary direct calls in PA, as the long watches seems to have issues under heavy load, maybe locking up resources in Consul or something.

Answer (score 0):

Update - repo now maintained by G-Research Open Source Software team. https://github.com/G-Research/consuldotnet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).